# Cannot Authenticate to Azure Functions with Azure Active Diectory Bearer Token

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, bearer-token

I am trying to make the AAD auth to work with my Azure Functions, but I keep having 401s...
My front end calls the azure functions with a Bearer token forge from the Front-End AAD AppId requesting access through `adal.AuthenticationContext.acquireToken("Azure Functions AAD AppId")`.
On the Azure Portal, I configured the Auth to use AAD with the same AppId. Either in Express or Advanced mode, I cannot make this work and I always receive 401... If I switch my functions to Level.Function, then this works if I pass over the token in the Http call (but I rather use AAD !!!)
Thanks for your insight,
Regards
Adrien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the level to Anonymous.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6992774c-8659-4424-854a-57b2d99e5309/azure-function-401-after-authentication-with-active-directory?forum=AzureFunctions

Answer (score 1):

I followed [Pete Skelly's guide](https://peteskelly.com/secure-functions-aad-2/) and works fine for me